# mcexam crashes with \includegraphics in \mcanswers

Tags: includegraphics, mcexam

I get a "! Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }." if I try to use \includegraphics within the \mcanswers environment using \answernum:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[output=exam
       ,numberofversions=2
       ,version=1
       ,seed=1
       ,randomizequestions=false
       ,randomizeanswers=true
       ,writeRfile=true
       ]{mcexam}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{mcquestions}
\question Which symbol means flammable?
    \begin{mcanswers}
    \begin{tabular}{m{.5cm}m{3cm}}
                    & Col2 \\
                    & Col2 \\
    \answernum{1} & \answer{1} \includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image.png} \\
    \answernum{2} & \answer[correct]{2} \includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image.png}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{mcanswers}
\end{mcquestions}
\end{document}
```

If I use the \mcanswerslist environment and place the \includegraphics in the \answer, it works fine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[output=exam
       ,numberofversions=2
       ,version=1
       ,seed=1
       ,randomizequestions=false
       ,randomizeanswers=true
       ,writeRfile=true
       ]{mcexam}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{mcquestions}
\question Which symbol means flammable?
    \begin{mcanswerslist}
    \answer \includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image.png}
    \answer [correct] \includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image.png}
    \end{mcanswerslist}
\end{mcquestions}
\end{document}
```

I would like to format the answer list to be in 2 columns to save space.  I tried the \minipage environment within the \mcanswerslist environment and that did not work.

Sorry, I cannot figure out how to include the actual graphics file here in my post, but you could substitute your own graphics file.

Comment: you can use `example-image.png` in examples, that is available for tests in standard distributions

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the package is doing but you can protect the `\includegraphcs` in an extra `{}` group:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[output=exam
       ,numberofversions=2
       ,version=1
       ,seed=1
       ,randomizequestions=false
       ,randomizeanswers=true
       ,writeRfile=true
       ]{mcexam}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{mcquestions}
\question Which symbol means flammable?
    \begin{mcanswers}
    \begin{tabular}{m{.5cm}m{3cm}}
                    & Col2 \\
                    & Col2 \\
    \answernum{1} & \answer{1} {\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image.png}} \\
    \answernum{2} & \answer[correct]{2} {\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image.png}}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{mcanswers}
\end{mcquestions}
\end{document}
```